# Low Level I/O using Read()

Tags: c, io

I am trying to use the `read()` function for the first time in *C*:

```
int file2p = open(curFilePath, O_RDONLY, 0);
char* buffer = NULL;
  while(read(file2p, buffer, sizeof(char*)) != 0){                 
            write(filep, buffer, sizeof(char*));
  }
close(file2p);
```

`filep` is a currently opened file I am writing too. For some reason this loop never ends.
I am trying to read files in a directory until the end of the file, and write what I grab into another files. (An archive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where on Earth do you think the data is going to be put?

Got buffer set to NULL

Got read the size of a character pointer.

Why not do

```
int file2p = open(curFilePath, O_RDONLY, 0);
char buffer[1024];
int len;
  while((len = read(file2p, buffer, 1024)) != 0){                 
            write(filep, buffer, len);
  }

close(file2p);
```

Comment: Sigh. I am not very good at C and all this buffer stuff. Thanks. So if the contents of the file exceed 1024 characters, will read be called again where it left off previously?

Comment: @Milwaukoholic Yes. Did the code suggested in this answer fix your problem? I'm asking because that would surprise me, actually.

Comment: @Milwaukoholic To be honest, the most surprising thing to me is that your program did not crash right away. :) But, you should still test the return values of `open(2)` and `read(2)` if they are negative, and if so, handle the error.

Comment: This answer will write extra bytes to the new file if the old file is not an exact multple of 1024 bytes in size.  You need to pass the return value of `read()` to as the number of bytes to write to `write()`.

Comment: Hence the use of `len`

Answer (score 1):

You do no error checking, which would diagnose your problem. Test `file2p` for being `-1`, dito the return value of `read(2)`.

And as others have said, use a valid buffer to store the input. :)